# Revealing module pattern and jquery failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file call text.js and it has

```
var Text = function(canvas){

  var textField = $('#textField'),
  addTextButton = $('#addText');

  var init = function(){
    addTextButton.click(function(){
      alert('won"t work?')
    }); 
  },

  resetTextField = function(){
   // it work if I put the selector here like var textField = $('#textField'),
    textField.val(''); // won't work
  };

  return{
    init:init
  }
}();
```

It's included in my index.html. In there I do init like

```
$(function(){ 
Text.init();
}());
```

The problem is the even't can't be fired. I think I messed up something.

Comment: [That works just fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/8ezcgpe2/) Please update the question with a [mcve] of the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: perhaps this text.js is loaded before the element with ID=addText is loaded

Comment: @JaromandaX but in my index.html I have $(function(){ }()) as wrapper to wrap Text.init()

Comment: I think if you console.log textField.length and addTextButton.length inside the init function, you'll find they are both ZERO

Comment: @NatelyJamerson: Yes, but you're not waiting for `ready` before looking up the elements. To do that, you need to move those `$()` calls *into* `init`. But really, there's no need for the `ready` stuff at all; just make sure your scripts are at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag, as recommended in [the YUI best practices](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Comment: @NatelyJamerson - yes, but you are initialising textField and addTextButton IMMEDIATELY, not as part of the init function

Comment: code is fine, put scripts in bottom of body,

Comment: by the way, the argument `canvas` will be undefined (not that you are using it)

Comment: @JaromandaX ignore the canvas, u are right, how do I solve this?

Comment: @A.T. tried before and after, both doesn't work

Comment: @NatelyJamerson I am wondering if "textField" and "addText" are't dynamically created , if so then the init should be called after they'r available in DOM.

Comment: @A.T., TJ answer's is correct. But why the canvas is undefined even I pass it through self execute function like `var Text = function(canvas){
console.log(canvas) // undefined??
}(window.canvas);`

Answer (score 1):

The code in `Text` is run **immediately**, and returns the object with `init` on it. If you run that code before the elements it looks up exist, for instance:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ... --->
<script src="text.js"></script><!-- Problem here -->
<script>
$(function(){ 
Text.init();
}());
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ... --->
<input id="textField"><input id="addText" type="button" value="Add">
<!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

... you'll end up with empty jQuery objects in `textField` and `addTextButton`.

Separately, you're also running the function you're trying to pass `ready` **immediately** (and then passing `undefined` into `ready`), the problem is here:

```
    $(function(){ 
    Text.init();
    }());
//   ^^---------- problem
```

You don't want those `()`. You want to pass the function into `ready`:

```
$(function(){ 
Text.init();
}); // <== Note no ()
```

If you're going to have the `init` method, it would be best to put all your initialization inside it rather than putting it in two places:

```
var Text = function(canvas){

  var textField, addTextButton;

  var init = function(){
    textField = $('#textField');
    addTextButton = $('#addText');
    addTextButton.click(function(){
      alert('won"t work?')
    }); 
  },

  resetTextField = function(){
   // it work if I put the selector here like var textField = $('#textField'),
    textField.val(''); // won't work
  };

  return{
    init:init
  }
}();
```

Note, though, that if you follow the [usual best practice](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) of putting your scripts at the *end* of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag, the elements defined above that will exist and be available, which would make using `ready` (and `init`) unnecessary. So if you control where the `script` tags go, that's an option.

So for instance:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ... --->
</head>
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<input id="textField"><input id="addText" type="button" value="Add">
<!-- ... -->
<script src="text.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){ 
Text.init();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this worked! But..

index.html's script I set canvas to window object
`window.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');`

Then I do this in my Text.js
`var Text = function(canvas){
console.log(canvas) // undefined??
}(window.canvas);`

why canvas is undefined?

Comment: @Jai: Nice catch. I just copied it from the OP's code without noticing.

Comment: @NatelyJamerson: Because you've *shadowed* the global `canvas` variable with a declared parameter to your `Text` function, and then called your `Text` function without any arguments, so the parameter's value is `undefined`. If you want to use the global, remove `canvas` from `var Text = function(canvas) ...`

Comment: why? I thought that's where the function receive the argument? why this time it's passed through the the bottom?

Comment: @NatelyJamerson: Sorry, misread your code above. I'd have to see the full context, but my guess is timing. If you can't work it out, post a question about it with an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the function once defined using `()` at a point where DOM is not loaded. Thus, all selectors return zero nodes.

```
var Text = function(canvas){
  // ...
}();
 ^^
```

Remove that. And when you call it, you need to instance the function first, and keep that instance reference (if you wish to).

```
var text = new Text();
    text.init();
```

Comment: revealing module need an instance? what's that for?

Comment: Because the function won't return method `init()` unless you invoke the parent function first.

Comment: nah it did. check's TJ answer.

Comment: The structure TJ rewrite the code is correct, but I kept the selectors out of `init`, so that's why you would need to instance `Text` first. :)